# How to program Multi Tab Task bar Preview like IE on Windows 7 in WPF?

Tags: wpf, windows-7, taskbar, preview

[IE8 on Win7 http://akashkava.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/IE8-on-Win7.png](http://akashkava.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/IE8-on-Win7.png)

Windows 7 has a new Task bar, and IE can display multiple tabs in the task bar previews, most of programs which does have not implemented this new api only shows one preview, I have an application where I have multiple tabs and I want to show each tab on this preview.

Let me elabourate more on it, I know that every new window created automatically gets a new Window in Switcher, but how to override to use it with tabbed document interface in WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly is possible, you can get familiar with the windows 7 taskbar api, I would recommend starting with the [windows 7 taskbar developer resources](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows7Taskbar).

Comment: Taskbar automatically shows preview for window, but not for tab items.

Comment: Yes, exactly, however the mechanism to control the previews generated as well as the items in the new taskbar context menu is all exposed through the new apis. In addition to the link I posted above you should checkout http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ee624070.aspx

Comment: The new version of Windows Code API does include my requirements but they arent very great while implementing, but anyway thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to get you started! I know this doesn't cover your scenario yet but it is planned in part 2, so keep an I on these:

http://dotnet.org.za/rudi/archive/2009/10/14/anatomy-of-the-windows-7-taskbar-tabbedthumbnail-part-1.aspx